Example of ZF model with non-absolute property
I read that ZF and the Axiom of Constructibility holds in Godel's $L$, i.e. for any $x \in L$ (not necessarily an arbitrary $x \in V$ as I understand although please correct me if am missing something here), we have:
$$
(\text{$x$ is constructible})^L \leftrightarrow (\text{$x$ is constructible})^V
$$
This is thanks to the absoluteness of the formula $(y=L_{\alpha})^L \leftrightarrow (y=L_{\alpha})^V$ so that the $y$ in $L$ is the same $y$ in $V$ (at least that's my interpretation...)
I would like however to get some counterexamples, i.e. a subclass $M$ of $V$ that satisfies $ZF$ and is defined by some property $P$, but which for some $y$ in $M$, we have:
$$
(\text{$y$ satisfies $P$})^M \not \leftrightarrow (\text{$y$ satisfies $P$})^V
$$
i.e. a subclass $M$ defined by $P$ but whereby $V \neq M$... Any help ?

The class $\mathrm{HOD}$ of hereditarily ordinal definable sets has this property, at least consistently.
The reference for (a strong version of) this claim is

MR0363887 (51 #142). Jech, Thomas J. Forcing with trees and ordinal definability. Ann. Math. Logic 7 (1974/75), 387–409.

First of all, this is a definable class, so there is a $P$ as desired. This is usually verified using the reflection theorem.
From the review of Jech's paper by Lev Bukovský: "Since $\mathrm{HOD}$ is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, one can define the class $\mathrm{HOD}$ inside the model $\mathrm{HOD}$, i.e., $\mathrm{HOD}^2=(\mathrm{HOD})^{\mathrm{HOD}}$. In this fashion, it is natural to set $\mathrm{HOD}^{\alpha+1}=(\mathrm{HOD})^{\mathrm{HOD}^\alpha}$, $\mathrm{HOD}^\lambda=\bigcap_{\xi<\lambda}\mathrm{HOD}^\xi$ for $\lambda$ limit. In general, even $\mathrm{HOD}^\omega$ may not be definable in the theory $\mathsf{ZFC}$. The main goal of the present paper is Theorem 1: Given an ordinal $\alpha$, there exists a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in which the sequence $\mathrm{HOD}^\xi$, $\xi<\alpha$, is definable and strictly decreasing."
Note this is a consistency result, and this is inevitable: if a property $P$ defines (provably in $\mathsf{ZFC}$) an inner model $M$, then $P^L=L$ (because $L^L=L$, by the absoluteness result that motivated your question), so the statement $M\ne V$ fails in $L$.

E. Caicedo ... thanks a lot for this ... just a little extra clarification, if we want to show that some axiom (say $A$) is consistent with ZF, in all cases, whenever we construct a submodel (say $L$) in $V$ s.t. both ZF and A holds in $L$, we also have to show that ZF+A is always "carried over" in the universe $V$ right ? (i.e. what I want to clarify is that although we don't need to check that A holds for each $x \in V$, but only for $x \in L$, i.e. still, for each $x \in L$, we have to show that from the "universal" perspective of $V$, A is still holds)

@LinkL If we show that $A$ holds in $L$, then you have shown that $\mathsf{ZF}+A$ is consistent. Using model-theoretic notation, what this shows is that $V\models L\models A$ or, if you want, that $A^L$ holds in $V$. If you want to verify $A^L$, you can either 1) argue within $L$ that $A$ holds, or 2) you prove the theorem that the assumption $V=L$ implies $A$, or 3) you explicitly prove $A^L$ in $V$ (which I assume is what you mean), which requires relativizing all quantifiers in $A$ to $L$. In particular, yes, if $A$ has the form $\forall x,\phi(x)$, what you need to prove in $V$ is that...

@LinkL $\forall x\in L,\phi^L(x)$. But this does not quite mean that for all $x\in L$ the property $\phi(x)$ holds. Rather, you need to prove for all $x\in L$ that the relativized property $\phi^L(x)$ holds. If $\phi$ has no quantifiers, then yes, $\phi^L(x)$ is the same as $\phi(x)$. But usually $\phi$ itself has quantifiers. For instance, if $\phi(x)$ has the form $\exists y,\psi(x,y)$ where $\psi$ is quantifier-free, proving $\phi^L(x)$ does not mean finding a $y$ such that $\psi(x,y)$. Rather, you need some such $y$ that, in addition, belongs to $L$. Similarly, if $\psi$ has...

@LinkL quantifiers, then you need to find some $y\in L$ such that $\psi^L(x,y)$, and to see what is involved in verifying $\psi^L(x,y)$ requires that you relativize all quantifiers in $\psi$ to $L$. Eventually you of course are at the level of atomic statements, and then, yes, such properties are absolute.

okay thanks a lot ! --- but just to press on a little bit further, if in order to verify $A^L$, it suffices (as per option (1)) that within $L$, we have that $A$ holds, then I would like to ask what would be the "added value" of proving that $A$ is absolute ? ... in my understanding (which is of a beginner sorry) we have to prove that a property is absolute in order to show that $A^L$ holds in $V$ and not just that $A^L$ holds within $L$ ... may I ask what I am missing in my logic ? thank you very much again ...

@LinkL Typically verifying some property $A$ involves verifying many different things. For example, $A$ may claim that there is a bijection between certain two sets. This verification may be involved, with many relativizations taking place. If, however, we know that some 'bits' of $A$ are absolute, then it becomes easier to see what to do and where to focus our efforts. in the example at hand, verifying that something is a bijection requires checking that it is a function and other things. But being a function is absolute, so if you have a candidate and you know that, in $V$, it is a ...

@LinkL function, then you know it is a function in your inner model, and you can concentrate your work on verifying the other properties that $A$ is demanding of it. Similarly, you may have an object in your inner model, and you want to check that the nice properties it has still hold in $V$. Some of these properties may be subtle, but others may just hold for free. Understanding absoluteness helps you direct your attention to those parts that are subtle and may require some work.
